# SWT Droptarget overlap issues

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, droptarget

I have a general drop target area for a specific transfer. The control that the drop target is on is a composite. Inside the composite I have a multitude of things. I recently added drop target to one of these objects inside of the composite. I've now run into an issue with the swt drag and drop, when I enter the first overall drop target, it behaves like one would expect. However, when I enter into the second drop target, that is nested within the original, it triggers a leave of the first target and an enter on the second one. This is causing all sorts of issues. Any idea on how to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want it to work?  Not leave the first, but do enter the second?

Comment: Well the strange fact is, they are using different transfer types. So I wouldn't even expect them to conflict. They are being used at two different times for two different functions. But this issue is causing them to conflict.

Comment: I don't think type matters here, the events are fired based on position.  And only one thing can be dropped in to at once I think, so to enter one thing, you have to leave the other.

Comment: :( thanks. I'll have to take another approach.

Comment: There may be an option...  take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe there can only be one 'active' drop target at a time, so I'm fairly sure that you can't make it not leave your composite.

But I think what you're trying to do may be possible.  To summarize, if you're dragging an object with type A, you want to be able to drop it anywhere in the composite.  If you have an object with type B, it should only be able to drop in the sub-component.

If so, how about this:  Let the sub component handle objects of both type A and B.  But if it gets a drop of type A, it forwards the event to it's parent.